# ajax success response issue

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue with the ajax jquery function.  This is may javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "login.php",
  data: {
    username: username,
    password: password
  },
  dataType: "text",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
  success: function (msg) {
    $("#button").ajaxComplete(function (event, request) {
      alert(msg == 'ok');
      if (msg == 'ok') {
        $('#load').show();
        setTimeout(function () {
          $("#username").css("background", "green");
          $("#password").css("background", "green"); // add red  color 
        }, 1000)
        setTimeout("submitForm()", 2000);
      } else {
        $('#load').show();
        setTimeout(function () {
          $("#username").css("background", "red");
          $("#password").css("background", "red"); // add red  color
          $('#load').hide();
          $('#button').show();
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I don't understand why the if(msg=="ok") return false,even if in the object "msg" there is a string "ok".

Comment: why ajaxcomplete inside the success handler ?

Comment: Heres a nice link for ya http://jsbeautifier.org/. Understand that the more you work on your question the more people will work on answers...

Comment: what, exactly, is returned by the ajax call into your `msg` object? Is it just a simple string, or is an object with a string in it?  Try using `console.log(msg);` to see what you get back.

Comment: you sure the success method is firing? try adding an error handler too. `,error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(jqXHR);console.log(textStatus);console.log(errorThrown);}`

Comment: Into msg is returned a string, "ok",generated by an echo statement in login.php.I know it by using typeof msg. It's incredible that the if(msg == "ok") return false!

Comment: I have resolved.The "include database.php" in login.php,where i make the DB connection cause the problem.I don't know why, but if i take off the include row, and i make the connection to database in the login.php, the ajax response is right. :|:| thanks at all.

Answer (score 0):

IThe success event takes a function with three parameters:
`data, textStatus, andjqXHR`.  I am assuming "ok" is the response given by the login.php, in which case, that is what will be the value of the `data` parameter.  So check the data parameter for the value of OK.

You might just want to `alert(data);` also, to see what exactly is getting returned.

See:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "login.php",
    data: {
        username: username,
        password: password
    },
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data == 'ok');
        if (data == 'ok') {
            $('#load').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#username").css("background", "green");
                $("#password").css("background", "green"); // add red  color 
            }, 1000)
            setTimeout("submitForm()", 2000);
        } else {
            $('#load').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#username").css("background", "red");
                $("#password").css("background", "red"); // add red  color
                $('#load').hide();
                $('#button').show();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it doesn't work.The alert always return false,even if "msg" object contains a string,and this string is actually "ok"(I've seen it using Firebug).It's courious that in another project,the same file login.php and that script jquery work!!Somone could help me?thanks!

Comment: what is the actual value of `data`?  That might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: The actual value of data is "ok"